# Assigning clusters/groups based on two sequential variables in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dplyr

**Context**: I have some spatial point data (i.e. lon/lat coordinates), and each point is associated with a date. I've clustered points that are close together, but I now want to split these clusters into groups so that if sorted by date the clusters are sequential and grouped together. Dates can have gaps, and I only want to slit when an observation fully divides a group, i.e. it's not just on the edge

Essentially, given the below `cluster` and `day` fields I want to generate `desired`.

```
   cluster day desired
1        1   1       1
2        1   1       1
3        1   2       1
4        1   4       1
5        2   6       2
6        2   7       2
7        2   8       2
8        1   8       3
9        3   9       4
10       3  12       4
11       3  12       4
12       2  12       5
13       2  14       5
14       3  18       6
15       3  19       6
```

Here's a complete example, note that the spatial coordinates are essentially irrelevant, I've just included them for completeness. Also, in my actual dataset `day` is a date object, but I've used an integer for simplicity.

```
library(ggplot2)
pts <- data.frame(rbind(
  cbind(lon = rnorm(5, 0, 0.1), lat = rnorm(5, 0, 0.1), 
        day = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 8)),
  cbind(lon = rnorm(5, 1, 0.1), lat = rnorm(5, 1, 0.1), 
        day = c(6, 7, 8, 12, 14)),
  cbind(lon = rnorm(5, 1, 0.1), lat = rnorm(5, 0, 0.1), 
        day = c(9, 12, 12, 18, 19))
))
hc <- hclust(dist(pts[c("lon", "lat")]))
pts$cluster <- cutree(hc, k = 3)
ggplot(pts) +
  geom_text(aes(lat, lon, label = day, col = as.factor(cluster)))
```

[image: first plot]

The grouping I want is this:

```
pts$desired <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
                 2, 2, 2, 5, 5,
                 4, 4, 4, 6, 6)
ggplot(pts) +
  geom_text(aes(lat, lon, label = day, col = as.factor(desired)))
```

[image: second plot]

Comment: Just to clarify, is your question "how to populate `desired`" or something else ?

Comment: Yes, how do I create the column `desired`? Sorry, I realize now this question is sort of confusing

Comment: Yes, finding where to make the cuts, then assigning groups based on those cuts. See the solution I just posted, which I think solves the problem, but not very elegantly

Comment: It looks as if "desired" always increments with each change of column "cluster". In that case you can use `cumsum(c(1L, diff(df$cluster) != 0))` to create it.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Since you came up with the way to set `desired` perhaps you want to post the complete answer (i.e. to get credit).  For `dplyr` with your suggestion, it may look something this `pts %>% arrange(day, cluster) %>% mutate(desired = cumsum(c(1L, diff(cluster) != 0)))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus That's it! Much nicer than mine. As steveb said, if you post this I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MattSM, you can go ahead and answer it yourself (and accept the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution comes courtesy of @docendodiscimus in the comments to the original question.

```
library(dplyr)
pts <- pts %>% 
  arrange(day, desc(cluster)) %>% 
  mutate(new_cluster = cumsum(c(1L, diff(cluster) != 0)))
all.equal(pts$desired, pts$new_cluster)
```